# Visual Interface to database mysql with Ruby ​​on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just looked at some tutorials Ruby on Rails, and I noticed that they use a lot of code on the command line, but do not feel comfortable with it only when it comes to database, my question is: There are tools you can use it visually ? ps: for my applications I want to use MySQL

Comment: Any application you write that needs to interface with a database will require you to learn SQL.  Whilst there are GUIs that can help, tbh it's not a difficult language.  You may as well take the plunge and start learning.

Comment: @ggyal, I know how use SQL, but I want a visual application for use with databases

Comment: If you know SQL, what is it that you expect a GUI to do for you?

Comment: Just do not like the look :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a free application with a GUI interface to MySQL:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/

If you're willing to pay, the best GUI app I've used is SQLyog:

https://www.webyog.com/

Comment: Oh, also, there's phpMyAdmin, which is a php MySQL website that you can run on the server.  It does some strange things, though, so I wouldn't really recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

the best tool I've used so far is SequelPro

https://www.sequelpro.com/

absolutely amazing tool and you can use it for free too!