# Is there a go-to GUI or visual interface that can be used with the PostgreSQL database in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, user-interface, rubygems

### QUESTION: Is there a go-to GUI or visual interface that can be used with the PostgreSQL database in Ruby on Rails?

---

#### 1. SUMMARIZING THE PROBLEM

It would be easier for me to work with the database in Rails if I had a good visual interface. I think that [RailsAdmin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) seems like a good option, but I am wondering what is the most popular/widely-used interace.

#### 2. WHAT I'VE TRIED

I have seen that people can integrate MySQL and the MySQL Workbench with Ruby on Rails. I am curious if there is an easy-to-use gem that provides a visual interface for the PostgreSQL database in Rails. Below are a couple of questions with some decent answers. However, I am curious about what would be the standard or go-to interface.

- [Visual Interface to database mysql with Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903267/visual-interface-to-database-mysql-with-ruby-on-rails)
- [Is there a "phpmyadmin" for Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554676/is-there-a-phpmyadmin-for-ruby-on-rails)

---

*Thank you in advance for reading my question and I look forward to reviewing the answers!*

Comment: You can use Pgadmin in your OS. In Rails you can create a view that requires (admin) authentication and format yourself that data you need into a table. Or use RailsAdmin. Though I have preferred to format my own namespaced admin section with only the data I need.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I appreciate it! I look forward to experimenting with it.

Comment: RailsAdmin or Active Admin are not comparable to MySQL Workbench or Pgadmin in any way. Its a gem that lets you rapidly create an admin GUI so that you can let administrators CRUD records without setting up scaffold controllers. Its still just a Rails app.

Comment: Totally different tools for different people. Most of the people that you let use RailsAdmin you wouldn't let near Pgadmin with a 10 foot pole. Pgadmin provides a visual interface for SQL - not for the buisness logic which your tables actually contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Table Plus](https://tableplus.com/) is great. Far better than Sequel Pro IMHO.

If you're looking for a Rails Admin alternative, I would check out [Active Admin](https://activeadmin.info/)

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation -- I look forward to trying it out. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

I heard Postico https://eggerapps.at/postico/ is nice.
You can write and test your sql there and see the results

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. It looks like this is a good alternative for Mac users specifically -- do I have that correct? I am currently using my Rails database with a VM that runs on an Ubuntu distribution of Linux, so I am not sure if this would work with my current coding environment. This does look like a good alternative for Mac users though. Thank you again for the recommendation!